# Migrate an SSL certificate from Heroku

Tags: ssl-certificate, vps, heroku

I have a functioning SSL certificate for a site I'm currently hosting on Heroku. I set it up myself once a year and a half ago but I've only ever done it that one time. I'm in the process of migrating to a VPS (Digital Ocean) and will be using the exact same domain. Most everything's good to go except setting up the SSL certificate and then pointing the DNS records at the right server

The guide Digital Ocean provides for SSL setup is for a new certificate. What I need to know is, if I have everything set up on the server according to their instructions, including all the right configurations and DNS records and the like, can I simply use the exact same `my_domain.crt` and `my_domain.key` files that I'm already using for Heroku? Or do I need to re-generate anything to run on the new VPS host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain name is staying the same, you can use the same key and certificate chain.